# needs 2 clicks to toggle after click on body

Tags: click, toggle, document-body

i bet you have seen this happen before. i have a frame appearing on click with toggle() and disappear on  body click. problem is, if the frame disappears on body click, it takes 2 clicks to trigger toggle()

```
$('CLASS1').hide();
$('CLASS2').toggle(function(){
    $('CLASS1').show();
    $("body").click(function(e){
        $('CLASS1').hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    },function(){   
    $('CLASS1').hide();

});
```

THANKS!