# at first, two clicks to toggle open a hidden element, but one click thereafter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple test html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
  .faqs { visibility: hidden; }
  .q { color:blue; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleElement(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility== 'hidden')
        { document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible'; }
    else
        { document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden'; }
}   
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="q"><a onclick="toggleElement('1');">toggle 1.</a></p>
<div class="faqs" id="1">
<p>Answer 1.</p>
</div>

<p class="q"><a onclick="toggleElement('2');">toggle 2.</a></p>
<div class="faqs" id="2">
<p>Answer 2.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this in Firefox or Chromium (Linux), it takes two clicks on either question to open the hidden 'answer'.  But after that it takes only a single click. Why is this?  --Or rather, how can I get it to open the hidden text with a single click always?

This question is similar to [needs 2 clicks to toggle after click on body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880313/needs-2-clicks-to-toggle-after-click-on-body), for which nobody answered.

-TYVM

Comment: p.s.   Same result when I substitute display:none and display:block.

Answer (score 2):

This check:

```
if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility== 'hidden'){...}
```

is not working since there is no inline style for `style.visibility`, therefore the first time it's setting the value to `hidden` and the second time, it's ok, and now is working.

To solve this, the easiest way is to add an inline style to the elements like:

```
<div class="faqs" id="1" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

If you don't want to use inline styles, you can can use `getComputedStyle()`, which returns all current styles for the element.

You use it like that:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someIdHere'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    top = style.getPropertyValue('top');
```

Comment: Or just switch to classes and check for className.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function toggleElement(id)
{
    var element      = document.getElementById(id);
    var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    element.style.visibility = (elementStyle.visibility == 'hidden') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}
```

Initially the element does not have any visibility style with it. To get it work you can use *getComputedStyle* function like above.